# Finding next prime no of the input which ends with 1

Tags: java, primes

I'm trying to find the next prime no which ends with 1.This shows only the next prime.But i want to print the next prime that ends with 1.

```
int num=103;
for(l=num+1;;l++)
{
   for(k=2;k<l;k++)
   {
     if(l%k==0)
        break;
   }
   if(k==l)
   {
       System.out.println("Next prime no is:"+l);
       break;
   }    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we do something like this?

```
int num=103;
for(l=num+1;;l++)
{
   if(l%10==1)
   {
    for(k=2;k<l;k++)
    {
     if(l%k==0)
        break;
     }
     if(k==l)
     {
       System.out.println("Next prime no is:"+l);
       break;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Skipping 9 out of 10 loop iterations seems wasteful. Ignoring the "getting started" part of the problem, once ```l``` ends with 1, it can be incremented by 10 thereafter.  Also, of course, you only need to attempt division for k from 2 to √```l```

Comment: Yes true, there are many optimal ways to find the prime numbers, I haven't changed anything in the logic just added 1 extra line

Comment: Certainly it's better (as you did) to skip the number as soon as we know it doesn't end in 1, rather than determining whether it's prime and *then* skipping it because it does not end in 1.  I wonder whether that is part of the marking scheme for the assignment?  ;-)

Comment: Beyond the square root limit, If the number ends in '1`, and follows a prime, you can start the division attempts from '3' and only consider odd divisors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do better than the "add 1 and test every number that follows if it ends in 1 and is a prime" that @ShashankGupta suggests.  Once we've found the next number that ends in '1' (using arithmetic, not a loop) we only need to check every tenth number from then on:

```
public static int next_one_prime(int number)
{
    // next number ending in '1'
    number += 1 + Math.floorMod(-number % 10, 10); 

    outer: while (true)
    {
        for (int k = 3; k * k <= number; k += 2)
        {
            if (number % k == 0)
            {
                number += 10;
                continue outer;
            }
        }

        return number; // next prime ending in '1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Concerning  ```number += 11 - number % 10``` -- if number is initially given as 10, then this sets number to 21, skipping over 11, which happens to be the answer we ought to have found.

Comment: @another-dave, for the moment I'm going to use the defense that the OP implies that the number passed in is prime, so this situation doesn't arise.  ;-)

Comment: ```number = (number / 10) * 10 + 1``` should work for all initial values >= 0.

Comment: @another-dave, that didn't work for me as 101 kept mapping back to 101.  I've put in an ugly patch but I'm sure you're narrowing in on a better one.

Comment: Ah; now we're not sure what 'next' means if the input itself is a prime ending in 1.

Comment: @another-dave, I'm assuming that the function outputs a prime ending in '1' and that result can be fed back into the function to find the next prime ending in '1'.  So, 'next' would mean larger than the supplied argument.